# How tight should passengers wear the seat belt?

Tags: safety, seats

How tight should a passenger wear the seat belt?

During takeoff and landing and other moments the seat belt sign is on, I usually pull the belt as tight as possible. This is little uncomfortable, so I loosen it a bit when the seat belt sign is off. I think that one or maybe two fingers might fit between the seat belt and my body. 
Is this a good idea? Would wearing the belt as tight as possible give a greater risk of crushing my pelvis bone or something?

Please specify whether there is a difference between a situation where the seat belt sign is on and a situation where the sign is off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this document published by the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/safety/pilotsafetybrochures/media/seatbelt_web2.pdf) (about smaller GA planes but the topic is applicable)

> Tests have shown that slack in the restraint system should be minimal.
>   In an impact, your body keeps moving until the slack is taken out of
>   the restraint, but then must be abruptly stopped to “catch up” with
>   the airplane. The restraint should be adjusted as tightly as your
>   comfort will permit to minimize potential injuries.

Here is a [video of them testing the seats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8cAwR4_7Wg). You can see the waist lines of the dummies does not move very much.

Here is an [interesting research paper on the topic](http://soar.wichita.edu/bitstream/handle/10057/624/Amit%20Deshpande%20thesis.pdf?sequence=3), may be worth checking out.

A study was conducted by the DOT ["*Human Factors Associated With the Certification of Airplane Passenger Seats: Seat Belt Adjustment and Release*"](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA404285) on the difference between belt tension (as applied by a passenger) in both a cruise and emergency setting. This looks like the most conclusive numbers I can find on measured tension.

> An analysis of results indicate that most passengers (90%) tighten
>   the lap belt to a tension less than 7 lb. during normal flight
>   conditions and less than 10 lb. for an anticipated emergency.

Comment: Great answer, but I would like to offer a brief translation, "make it snug."